# How to correctly handle FFMPEG errors?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video, streaming, hls

In my project I need to read from a stream that sends live content in HLS format and then save this content locally in a specific folder appending this data from the previous record to the new ones.

I've noticed a bug that occurs when the stream crashs for some time.

When the live server gets back, the output that is recorded has only one frame, and in the console shows a warning message:

```bsh
Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 7499938, current: 4488960; changing to 7499939. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

How can I handle this? Is there any flag that stops the recording and kills the process when a error is detected?

Obs: The FFMPEG command that I'm using has this shape, where application and stream are changed to valid values before the command is used:

```bsh
ffmpeg -i http://172.17.0.1:1935/${application}/${stream}/playlist.m3u8 -vcodec copy -c copy -f hls -hls_flags append_list output/playlist.m3u8
```

Comment: Start with the [HTTP protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#http) and [HLS demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hls-1) documentation. There is the `-xerror` global option, but I'm not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion llogan, I'll read the docs about this topic. Actually I'm doing this with Node.js.